# Positioning image in anchor tag with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using the standard bootstrap nav bar template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" id="brand-container" href="#">
                <img id="brand-in-navbar" alt="NBA" src="nba.png" />
              </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              </form>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
```

The part I am working on is:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" id="brand-container" href="#">
   <img id="brand-in-navbar" alt="NBA" src="nba.png" />
</a>
```

The CSS I have for the img is:

```
#brand-in-navbar {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```

The issue here is, the logo i used isnt being positioned correctly and it is out of the anchor tag's borders:

[image: logo]

I want to position the logo in the top left corner so that the bottom isnt sticking out of the nav bar. Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Since you're using the `<img>` tag, why are you using the `background` property in css for it?

Comment: @Kapobajza you are correct, made edits to try and fix the issue.

Comment: How about you set the `position` property to `absolute` and then place the image using `top` and `left` properties. Like this: `position: absolute; top: 0px left: 0px` . I am not quite sure about the top and left property values,experiment a little with them if the values aren't correct.

Comment: Or try setting the `margin` and `padding` properties to 0 of the anchor element with the `brand-container` id.

Comment: @Kapobajza that makes all the links to the right of the logo overlap with it

Comment: Forgot that little detail about `absolute` ,try what I wrote earlier: `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` of the anchor element with the `brand-container` id.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you're trying to set a background image on an actual image?

You don't need to do that.

If your html is this, and the image src is valid...

```
<a class="navbar-brand" id="brand-container" href="#">
   <img id="brand-in-navbar" alt="NBA" src="nba.png" />
</a>
```

You could just resize the image, for example...

```
#brand-in-navbar {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Just adjust the height as needed.

Also see this - http://www.bootply.com/0jZyA6mx3F#

Comment: Is the image displaying, and is it the same issue as your original post?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, drop the background stuff since you're already using `<img>`. Next, is your `<a>` set to `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` with the logo's dimensions?  If not, try that and it should align properly.

If it's still having issues, check the padding and margins for both elements.  Seeing your full CSS would help, but that should get you on the right track.

Comment: im using bootstraps standard nav-bar template: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Comment: It looks like `.navbar-brand` is using padding which is causing the problem.  Override/remove it and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
.brand-in-navbar{
  height:100%;
}
```